# what is a better tool for collaborating with others than email?

Tags: project-management, collaboration

I'm a developer and need to collaborate with an UI designer and a project manager. so there are a lot of documents we need to share and the project manager will assign me tasks about the project. Instead of email and dropbox, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: You could use a tool like Mingle(paid) or Acunotes(free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at varying other online collaboration tools out there. I use Clinked (http://clinked.com/) at work, and although we use a the paid version there is a free one for 5 users or less so maybe you could check that out?

Answer (score 1):

My team and I have been using [Wrike](https://www.wrike.com/) for almost a year now, and I have to say it’s pretty neat in terms of collaboration. We have to deal with lots of documentation and edit-approve iterations, and Wrike made it all really simple. Basically, each member of the team just opens a needed doc, edits it, saves, and it’s automatically uploaded as a new version, so no download and no multiple versions of the same doc. And every time there’s been a change it sends a notification to my e-mail, so it’s really easy to keep track on what’s going on with a task. It’s also integrated with Google docs, so you can choose whatever suits your needs better. I, personally, love its e-mail integration (it converts my e-mails into tasks, I just need to add Wrike into the e-mail’s CC and it will be transferred into the app) and Outlook add-in, as it helps to keep all our data in one place. It works perfectly for our task management needs, too. Especially with its Activity Stream that makes it really easy to stay updated with the tasks’ changes and discuss any coming issue.

Hope you’ll find it useful too! Let me know how it went afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this list of 43 project management software alternatives useful:
http://blog.timedoctor.com/2011/02/02/43-project-management-software-alternatives

My personal favorites are Basecamp, Time Doctor and Dropbox. These programs have helped my team in a lot of ways especially productivity. I'm sure you'll find yours there too. It's the most helpful and comprehensive list I was able to get.